# Create an Iterator with a selection

Tags: pyqgis, iterator

I'm blocked with creation of an iterator in my script.
I want coordinates of selected points.
If I do that, it works, it print all points coordinates

```
##point=vector
layer = processing.getObject(point)
it = layer.getFeatures()
for i in it:
    x = i.geometry().asPoint().x()
    y = i.geometry().asPoint().y()
    print "X Coord :  %f" %x
    print "Y Coord :  %f" %y
    print
```

So after I add my selection. But it crash.

```
##point=vector
layer = processing.getObject(point)
nbr = QgsExpression( "ID LIKE '%-1'" )
itnbr = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( nbr ) )
for i in itnbr:
    x = i.geometry().asPoint().x()
    y = i.geometry().asPoint().y()
    print "X Coord :  %f" %x
    print "Y Coord :  %f" %y
    print
```

I have an OGR error message : `invalid data source`

What causes that?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. How are you defining `layer`?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to put it in my post `layer = processing.getObject(point)`

Comment: And point is a point vector layer in qgis

Comment: What does it say if you use `print layer`?

Comment: `<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x123d49cc8>`

Comment: I'm not sure that OGR message in my post is really important because it returns it every times. But it's certain that with selection, my iterator doesn't work. It returns nothing.

Comment: Are you sure your expression is correct? What features are you trying to get from your expression?

Comment: My expression is good, yes. I test it with print to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is probably related to type field of your shapefile. Generally, ID values are numerical and you are using a Wildcard Character (%) with a minus sign (-) for your search. It's only logical if shapefile has a string field in attributes table. To test my approach I used a shapefile point layer (25 features) with ID field and following version of your code:

```
import processing

point = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/random_points.shp'

layer = processing.getObject(point)
nbr = QgsExpression( u"ID LIKE '%1'" )
#nbr2 = QgsExpression( u"MARKER_COL LIKE '%-ue'" )

itnbr = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( nbr ) )

for i in itnbr:
    x = i.geometry().asPoint().x()
    y = i.geometry().asPoint().y()
    print "X Coord :  %f" %x
    print "Y Coord :  %f" %y
    print
```

After running the code at Python Console of QGIS I got:

```
X Coord :  390945.280000
Y Coord :  4451149.380000

X Coord :  439639.970000
Y Coord :  4455290.050000

X Coord :  366311.250000
Y Coord :  4433366.270000
```

for IDs 1, 11 and 21; as expected.

Afterward, I modified only one record in attributes table (MARKER_COL field); as it can be observed at following image:

[image]

for running following version of your code:

```
import processing

point = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/random_points.shp'

layer = processing.getObject(point)
#nbr = QgsExpression( u"ID LIKE '%1'" )
nbr2 = QgsExpression( u"MARKER_COL LIKE '%-ue'" )

itnbr = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( nbr2 ) )

for i in itnbr:
    x = i.geometry().asPoint().x()
    y = i.geometry().asPoint().y()
    print "X Coord :  %f" %x
    print "Y Coord :  %f" %y
    print
```

Result was:

```
X Coord :  390945.280000
Y Coord :  4451149.380000
```

for 'bl-ue' record (MARKER_COL field); again as expected.

Comment: Indeed, my ID field is a string one like 12-34. My data provider gives me it like that. It contains row number and number in row of vines. I found a solution too : I create a list with `itnbr` and make my loop on it, weird... but it works. What is `u` just before expression ?